# Java grph library: Exception on toools.os.OperatingSystem.getLocalOS()

Tags: java, linux

I'm using grph library for a university project (www.i3s.unice.fr/~hogie/grph/) 
but i have a problem only on Linux with that library, when i create a new Graph object, i receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.elendev.wesproject.graph.GraphFactory.main(GraphFactory.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at toools.os.OperatingSystem.getLocalOS(OperatingSystem.java:47)
    at grph.Grph.setCompilationDirectory(Grph.java:353)
    at grph.Grph.<clinit>(Grph.java:246)
    ... 1 more
```

I tried to call directly getLocalOS function, with:

```
System.out.println(toools.os.OperatingSystem.getLocalOS());
```

and i receive the same exception. I cannot find information about that library, and the project launched on a macbook works perfectly.

The operating system i'm currently using is gentoo linux 32bit. 
And the jdk version is: 1.7.0_65

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this can count as an answer, but it could at least help to solve the issue:

The exception comes from the `toools.os.OperatingSystem.getLocalOS` method. Although the .JAR file from the website that you mentioned has a whopping 39 *megabytes*, the source code of *this* class is not contained in it.

There seems to be no information available about this class at all. Neither Google nor Maven finds anything related to the `toools` package. One has to assume that it is an abandoned utility class that passed away a long time ago.

However, the method in question can be disassembled to the following code:

```
  public static OperatingSystem getLocalOS()
  {
    if (localOS == null)
    {
      if (new RegularFile("/etc/passwd").exists())
      {
        if (new Directory("/proc").exists())
        {
          if (new RegularFile("/etc/fedora-release").exists()) {
            localOS = new FedoraLinux();
          } else if (ExternalProgram.commandIsAvailable("ubuntu-bug")) {
            localOS = new UbuntuLinux();
          } else {
            localOS = new Linux();
          }
        }
        else if (new Directory("/Applications").exists()) {
          localOS = new MacOSX();
        } else {
          localOS = new Unix();
        }
      }
      else if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {
        localOS = new Windows();
      } else {
        localOS = new OperatingSystem();
      }
      localOS.name = System.getProperty("os.name");
      localOS.version = System.getProperty("os.version");
    }
    return localOS;
  }
```

From this, you can possibly derive the conditions that must be met in order to properly detect your OS as a linux OS. Particularly, when there is a file named `/etc/passwd`, and a directory `/proc`, this should be sufficient to identify the OS as a `Linux`. You may want to give it a try...

Comment: Thank you marco for your reply.I also posted the question on the library forum, and the author released a new version that fix the problem. I think that this toools library is internal to grph.

Comment: The version to install for fix that problem si 1.5.24